# What's the difference between Encoding.GetEncoding(1255) and Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)?

Tags: c#, .net, encoding

I have a C# form based program and have been using

`System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)`

but I've had trouble reading non-English characters, I've discovered

`System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1255)`

works however I don't know the implications of changing this so I'm hoping someone can shed some light on the difference and possible implications.

Answer (score 6):

When you use GetEncoding(1252), you're specifying the [Windows-1252 Encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), which specifies a latin alphabet for Western Europe.  GetEncoding(1255) is the [Windows-1255 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1255), which is used to write Hebrew.

Answer (score 3):

Character encoding 1255 includes Hebrew symbols whereas 1252 is geared towards Western Languages. Is it the case that the non-English symbols happen to be Hebrew?

Comment: Correct, the characters are Hebrew

Answer (score 3):

1252 is Windows-1252 Western European (Windows)

1255 is Windows-1255 Hebrew (Windows)

source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encodinginfo.codepage.aspx

Answer (score 3):

Your encoding should always match the one that was used to create the file. If there is no metadata (or person) available to guide this selection, then the only thing to do would be to try each one and see which is legible. Since this is apparently in a language that you don't know, you may need to ask someone who speaks the language if it's legible. Do you know anyone who can read Hebrew?

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use one of the "named" Unicode encodings,  eg., [`Encoding.UTF8`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8.aspx). But, to answer your question - [page 1252 is "Western European (Windows)" and 1255 is "Hebrew (Windows)".](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx)

If you're not aware, code pages are pretty much [a relic of ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page) and you should try to stick with Unicode where possible.

Comment: Hi Mark, When using UTF8 I can load the file but I see ��� instead of Hebrew characters. Should UTF8 work? Thanks

Comment: @Jonathan - Where is this data coming from? Is it being typed, or loaded from a file? Copied and pasted?